# unable to select data in autocomplete text box in asp.net mvc4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am unable to select a particular item in autocomplete textbox in MVC4. 
I am getting the matching data and i am appending it to div (showresults). but unable to select one item. Please some one help me. Please let me know if more information is needed.
Below is the code in jquery:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({       
source: function (request, response) {        
    var customer = new Array(); alert(request);
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Enrollment/Member/GetNamesList",
        data: { "term": request.term },            
        success: function (data)
        {
            $('#showresults ul').html('');
            $('').appendTo($('#showresults ul'));

            $(data).each(function () {
                $('<li><a href="" title="' + this.FirstName + '" data-val="' + this.UHID + '">' + this.FirstName + '</a></li>').appendTo($('#showresults ul'));
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {               
            alert("select");                
        },
        error: function (msg)
        {
            alert("error occured");
        }            
    });
}
})
```

Comment: Can you provide the data that you are getting in Success?

Comment: in success i am getting ID and Name. ex: <ul><li><a href="" title="Habib" data-val="1001"> Habib</a></li></ul>

Comment: Hi  user3263194 please respond, I m sorry for my late response. This is very urgent for me.

Comment: i think the problem style display:none may block your data from displaying in auto complete box.

Comment: Hi Ravi Kiran, i did not added that css in my project. Could you please provide me any solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are getting data as you mentioned, then please check the fiddle below, I'm able to select the    item.
var data =  [
{
    "id": "1001",
    "value": "Habib"
},
{
    "id": "1002",
    "value": "Habib2"
}];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dvgxga2j/28/

Comment: can you please let me know which is the js file you have used for this. for me its not working. The js reference i am using is <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>. Please let me know if it is not the one you have used.

Comment: I'm using version 1.11.1. You can use jquery-1.11.1.min.js.
Find the link from the left side Resources in the fiddle.

Also add jquery-ui.css.

Comment: I have added both the files you have mentioned. But still its not working for me. I have no idea where i am missing. does jquery-1.11.1 conflict with other js files. The remaining js files we use in project are: <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> and jquery-ui.js, jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js, jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js.

Comment: If you are adding jquery-1.11.1 file, then you can remove jquery-1.10.2. Because the higher version supports whatever is required from 1.10.2.